# C++ Why the operator-> breaks the nested operator() call?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

When I use the dereference operator on the pointer to class with overloaded opearator() (aka functors) - it works like a charm:

```
struct Functor {
    int operator()(int a, float b) {
        return a+b;
    }
};

Functor g;
Functor * f = &g;
g(1,2.);
(*f)(1,.2);
f->operator()(1,2.f);
```

But the form

```
// f->(1,2.f); // doesn't compile (expected unqualified-id)
```

Why is that?

Comment: `f->()` is not syntactically valid in C++ (or C), for better or worse.  Are you asking why the language designers chose not to allow it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck But why the syntax is not correct? I expected the -> to be a short cut for (*ptr) so if we could apply (*ptr)() after the dereference and priority brackets - why then we couldn't apply the () to output of ->

Comment: `f->` is an "alias" for `*f.` not what you think.

Comment: @Slava oh, I see.. now it make sense because of the dot '.'

Comment: @Slava btw if -> is an alias for (*f). then why it doesn't work with pointers to member functions:

Comment: @Slava like this : class Pointee {
public:
    explicit Pointee(int val) {
        v = val;
    }
    int process(int a, int b) {
        return a+b+v;
    }
private:
    int v;
};


int main() {
    int (Pointee::*p1)(int,int) = &Pointee::process;
    Pointee var(123);
    Pointee * pvar = &var;
    
    (var.*p1)(1,2);
    std::cout << (var.*p1)(1,2);
    
    pvar->(*p1)(1,2); // doesn't compile

}

Comment: @barney `.*` is *one* operator – the "pointer-to-member dereference operator". The corresponding operator when you have a pointer is `->*`. The correct syntax is `(pvar->*p1)(1,2)` (or `((*pvar).*p1)(1,2)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the dot (`.`) operator is used to access members and call methods on an object. In your example, you could have used in the following way:

```
g.operator()(1, 2.);
```

and it would have compiled fine. Instead, you call the operator in the *equivalent* (and more conventional) notation, as follows:

```
g(1,2.);
```

which is nice and clean. What you are trying to do is achieve the same clean operator call, but from a pointer, using the `->` notation, thinking that the same magic will apply. Sadly, it does not work that way. In C++, `p->a()` is a shorthand for `(*p).a()`. It is, in other words, a way to

1. dereference a pointer -- `*p`;
2. call a method (or access a member) from *that dereferenced object* -- `(*p).a()`;

That dereferenced object is no longer a pointer (the parenthesis around `*p` achieve that), which is why the  dot operator can be called. So when you write:

```
f->(1,2.f);
```

what you are writing is something like:

```
(*f).(1, 2.f);
```

which is not valid C++ since `(*f)` does not represent an address to a `Functor` object. Note that:

```
f->operator()(1,2.f);
```

is valid because it means:

```
(*f).operator()(1, 2.f);
```

which works. It is equivalent to the first line I wrote above: `g.operator()(1, 2.);`.

Hope this helps.